# Best way to determine VCP COM port in .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a couple of different devices connected by VCP and I need to determine the port they are on using C#.  It's important for tracking purposes, too.  If the device is unplugged and plugged back in or loses power momentarily, sometimes the COM port will change.

I'm looking for a reliable way of determining this.  Currently, the best method I've found is to locate the device using the PID and parse the COM port from the device Name ie

```
    public static bool IsDevice ( ManagementObject Device, string PID ) {
        try {
            return new Regex ( string.Format ( @"USB\\VID_[^&]+&PID_{0}\\.*", PID ) ).IsMatch ( ( string ) Device["DeviceID"] );
        } catch ( Exception ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static string GetVCP_COMPort ( ManagementObject Device ) {
        try {
            return new Regex ( @".*\((COM[0-9]+)\).*" ).Match ( ( string ) Device["Name"] ).Groups[1].Value;
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

...

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher ( "Select * from Win32_PnPEntity" );
var coll = searcher.Get ();

foreach ( ManagementObject o in coll )
    if ( IsDevice ( o, PID ) ) {
        var port = new SerialPort ( GetVCP_COMPort ( o ) );
    }
```

I'm pretty comfortable with my method for finding the device ie `IsDevice`, but parsing the COM port from the device name looks error prone - easily broken if a device doesn't have a name following the exact pattern of `Device Name (COMXY)`.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only thing required is to just improve your WMI search query.  Then DeviceID will be the COM port.

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher ( string.Format ( "select DeviceID from Win32_SerialPort where PnPDeviceID like '%PID_{0}%'", PID ) );
```